How to run 2 or more tests from a test suite and use variable? Robot Framework
when I run two tests from a test suite with the command:
robot -d results --include Test1ORTest2 tests/testfile.robot
I have multipe test in the testfile and want to run only these two, what works good with the command, but the problem is that I want to use a variable form Test1 and use it in Test2.
In test1 I get the value and that works like I exepect.
${VAR}    get element attribute    xpath=locator     value

set global variable    ${VAR}

In test2 I want to use the defined variable from test1, but I'm not getting to value I expect.
input text      xpath=locator       ${VAR}

The input text is: ''
So I'm getting nothing... I tried a few options, but I don't get it right...
For example:
${VAR}    get element attribute    xpath=locator     value

${VAR_FOR_TEST2}  set global variable    ${VAR}

input text      xpath=locator      ${VAR_FOR_TEST2}

I tried different options as shown above, but I also tried searching online for answers and try to recreate those solutions, but I don't get it to work properly.

Did you Log    ${VAR} before setting it global, to check the value?

@Helio Yeah I did and it works fine. I use the ${VAR} value in the first test aswell, but in test2 it's gone and idk why

Try the Set Suite Variable

The second way you tried, does not work because Set Global Variable does not return a value. The first, looks OK, but you should escape the $.
This is documentation, screen capture on RIDE:

As you can see there is a recommendation to escape the $. Your step would be:
set global variable    \${VAR}    ${VAR}

You could also try the new VAR syntax:


With the escaped it works! Thanks for the help @Helio
